# jsf 1.2 rerendring ui tag generates div tag

Tags: ajax, jsf, richfaces, seam

I've got the following piece of jsf 1.2 and richface 3.3.3

```
<s:div id="tree_nav" styleClass="unit size4of5">
        <ul id="ul">
                    <li>< <a:form>
                        <a:commandLink value="test" reRender="tree_nav"
                            action="#{menuItemHome.setMenuValue(ldcMenu.id)}" />
                    </a:form> 

                    </li
    </ul>
```

when the page is first loaded it generates this html:

```
<div id="main_nav" class="line">
<div id="tree_nav" class="unit size4of5">
<ul id="ul">
<span id="menu:0:j_id36">
<li>
```

when i do a rerender it generates the following:

```
<div id="main_nav" class="line">
<div id="tree_nav" class="unit size4of5">
<div id="ul" style="margin-left: 2em">
<span id="menu:0:j_id36">
<li>
```

Anyonne know why it genereates a div instead of ul after a rerender?

Comment: I'd imagine that something's broken in `<s:div>` component or renderer. You could try upgrading Seam.

Comment: to what verion then i use  2.2.2.Final?

Comment: Sorry, it was just a wild guess. I am not familiar with Seam. But I think it is worth a bug report over there.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe its because you are using `s:decorate` or include or something similar that renders a div.

Comment: Why would the ul dissapear then and the id from the ul get changed to the div?